# Can const member function return a non-const pointer to a data member?

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

Code goes first:

```
class A
{
    public:
        ...
        int *foo() const
        {
            return _px;
        }
    private:
        int *_px;
}
```

The member function `foo` returns a non-const pointer to `private` member `_px`, which, I think, opens a door to modifying member `_px`, right?

Is `foo` a `const` member function? Should I add a `const` in front of the return type?

**UPDATE**

What a const-member-function should guarantee is that, it cannot change any data-member, right?

In my case, function `foo` doesn't open a door to modifying `class A`s data-member `_px`, but a door to modifying what `_px` pointing to, So my question is, does this violate what a const-function should guarantee?

Comment: What does the compiler say with warning enabled ?

Comment: @ArunMu gcc 4.6.1 says nothing.

Comment: @ArunMu, well, seems nothing.

Comment: `const` is sadly not transitive across references / pointers.

Comment: Whether or not it violates anything depends on the purpose of the class, the pointer and the function. Technically it is OK.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A `const` member function can only return a `const` pointer or reference to a member.

However, your example isn't returning a pointer to a member; it's returning a copy of a member that happens to be a pointer. That is allowed in a `const` member function (even if the pointer happens to point to another member).

This would not be allowed (note that it's now returning a reference):

```
int *& foo() const {return _px;}
```

but this would (returning a `const` reference):

```
int * const & foo() const {return _px;}
```

Comment: Sir, your explanation is pretty clear and right. IMO, `foo` in `class A` opens a door to modifying what `_px` pointing to, which,I think, makes `foo` a non-const member function, right?

Comment: @Alcott: `const` on a member function only protects members of the object itself, not any further levels of indirection. So within the function `_px` is effectively `int * const`; the pointer itself can't be modified, but its target can be.

Comment: Actually you _can_ return a non `const` reference from a `const` member function like so: `struct O { int* a; int& getA() const { return *a; }`

Answer (score 5):

`int *_px` becomes `int *const _px` inside a const member function this implies that the pointer cannot be reseated but the data pointed to is still modifyable. Further your function returns a copy of the pointer so it does not matter anyways.

Answer (score 5):

It does not open a door to modifying `_px` but rather what `_px` points to. It's up to you to decide whether you want to allow this or not.

For example, an `iterator::operator->` would return a non-const pointer and `const_iterator::operator->` would return a const pointer. Both methods can be const themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for your case it can. However, it's generally advised to not to do this, because it allows changing constant objects:

```
void f(const A& a) 
{
  *(a.foo()) = 42; // damn!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example see the std::streambuf pointers:

```
protected:
   char* pbase() const;
   char* pptr() const;
   char* epptr() const;
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pptr

Comment: How do I write a good answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer